# DD4T.Templates.Base.BaseComponentTemplate Serialization

Tags: dd4t

Has anyone written a JSON serializer for this?

Seems a mistake to have hard-baked in the serialization functionality within this class, specificially to XmlSerializer, but I'll stand corrected as to any reasons why?

Comment: I often thought of publishing in JSON format rather than XML for MVC type applications, however I always changed my mind when I remember that Tridion manages a lot of content in XHTML format (RTF fields) and this corresponds a lot nicer (and is more easily parsed) as XML

Comment: Thanks.  I guess the root of my overall question is that there are so many ways to do something I am almost 'scared' to commit for fear of it not being best practice.  I guess that's the power (and pain) with Tridion, however.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason why the data format (in our case XML) is hardcoded, is that DD4T controls the input as well as the output of the process. The XML is intended to be consumed in a web application by the DD4T factories / providers.

If you want to publish JSON and consume it using custom application logic, you don't really need DD4T - just write a template that does this. If you just want to access the Tridion content model on the front end using Java or .NET, and you don't care about the data format in which the pages and components get published, DD4T is the framework for you.

Answer (score 13):

As I understand it, DD4T is an open source project. Presumably no-one has yet felt the need for this enhancement. My suggestion would be to build it yourself, and obviously, also contact the DD4T team to see if your enhancement can benefit others by being integrated into the project

Comment: Looking further into this it's a bit of a waste of time anyway, as whatever comes back from OData.svc is already encoded into a string within 'content', therefore the JSON data would also be (by design) and would have to be parsed out anyway.   Can output from CP's be forced to conform to a data contract on publish instead of just being chucked into a string literal?

Comment: You would have to perform the validation in your template - I do this all the time.

Comment: In the DD4T template?  I'm loathe to write something from scratch when a solution may have already been developed - has anyone written any utterly generic templates that compose any and all nested components in the same way DD4T does? We have about 100 templates using XSLT mediator but they are more or less coupled to the schemas.  The 'editor' should only be concerned with composing content in a semantic way (which is why I like DD4T as it can be the same template many times with a more semantic name!)

Comment: Sooner or later, your template transforms your input to your output. To have much value, that implies knowledge of your input. All that DD4T does is move the templating to the front end. It doesn't stop your templates having to know about the input. But don't worry: often writing something from scratch is a more productive activity than an eternal quest for a ready-made "solution". BTW - standard Tridion templating also supports "the same template many times with a more semantic name".

Comment: I'm assuming you mean your article here - http://nunolinhares.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/validating-content-on-save-part-1-of.html  - I don't understand how that ensures the output is valid, I could take perfectly valid content and destroy it with some malformed template very easily.  What is needed is some   algorithm that can execute quickly in O(n) time or similar that proves the output is correct.

Comment: @mpaton - Don't feel bad about not understanding. For the record: perfection malforming algorithm correctness proofs are unlikely to execute in anything better than O(n4~*)

Comment: Why would validating content on save ensure the output of pages is valid? No, I obviously meant a TBB that runs at the end of a template to validate the output of that template - be it against a XSD (XHTML validation was all the hype only a few years ago) or against a data model.

Comment: If you do find an algorithm that can do it in O(n), please share it, because it would be good press if the P = NP proof came out of the Tridion Stack Exchange. We'd probably make it all the way out of beta!

Comment: Haha, I did consider that and what I'd do with the $1m.  Most of the proofs from mathematics genii seem to indicate O(n^2), however.